# How do I check if multiple text contents are in an element?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a component like this:

```
export const MyComponent = props => {
    return (
        {
            props.options.map(option =>
                <>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" id={option.id} name="group" value={option.id} />
                        <label htmlFor={option.id}>{option.label}</label>
                    </div>
                    <span>Some other text</span>
                </>
            )
        }
    )
}
```

And in my test, I want to make sure that both that all the radio buttons are rendered with the right label text and the extra text in the `span` are present.

```
import { render, screen, within } from '@testing-library/react'

describe('MyComponent', () => {
    const props = {
        options: [
            { id: 1, label: 'Apple' },
            { id: 2, label: 'Banana' },
            { id: 3, label: 'Cherry' },
        ]
    }

    it('Renders the component', () => {
        render(<MyComponent {...props} />)
        
        const options = screen.queryAllByRole('radio')
        expect(options).toBeArrayOfSize(3)

        options.forEach((option, index) => {
            const { getByText } = within(option)
            expect(getByText(props.options[index])).toBeInTheDocument() // Assertion fails
            expect(getByText("Some other text")).toBeInTheDocument() // Also fails
        })
    })
})
```

However, I'm getting errors on the two `expect` assertions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react"
import { MyComponent } from "./MyComponent"

describe("MyComponent", () => {
  const props = {
    options: [
      { id: 1, label: "Apple" },
      { id: 2, label: "Banana" },
      { id: 3, label: "Cherry" },
    ],
  }

  it("Renders the component", () => {
    render(<MyComponent {...props} />)

    const options = screen.queryAllByRole("radio")
    expect(options).toHaveLength(3)

    props.options.forEach((option) => {
      const label = screen.getByLabelText(option.label)
      const radioBtn = screen.getByRole("radio", { name: option.label })

      // Need to use getAllByText query since the string "Some other text" is repeated... getByText will throw because of multiple matches
      const [someOtherText] = screen.getAllByText("Some other text")

      expect(label).toBeInTheDocument()
      expect(radioBtn).toBeInTheDocument()
      expect(someOtherText).toHaveTextContent(someOtherText.textContent)
    })
  })
})
```